# "if" statements in batch: file crashes when the input is supposed to be a number, but instead has words with spaces

Tags: variables, batch-file, if-statement, set

So,  I have a set /p thing in a batch file. For the user to proceed, they must type "2". I can't seem to find my specific problem anywhere.

```
@echo off
echo "What is 1+1"

set /p oneplusone=Type Answer Here: 

if %oneplusone%==2 goto correct
if %oneplusone% neq 2 goto incorrect

:correct
cls
echo Correct!
pause
goto youranswer

:incorrect
cls
echo Wrong.
pause
goto youranswer

:youranswer
cls
echo You answered: %oneplusone%
```

Now, if the user types a number/word with no spaces, everything works out, and it shows your answer as wanted.

However, say if you type something like "hi there" with a space, the batch file closes immediately. This only happens when the answer needs to be a number, and you type something that involves a space.

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change your IF statement to use quotes. `if "%oneplusone%"=="2" goto correct`

Comment: Kudos to you, squashman!

Comment: Using `==` comparison and `""` forces string comparison; you could state `set /A oneplusone=oneplusone` to convert the value to a number and then use `if %oneplusone% equ 2`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if your answer is a number using this:

```
set /a test=%oneplusone%*1
if %test%==0 goto notValid
```

and have another label, making your code this

```
@echo off
echo "What is 1+1"

set /p oneplusone=Type Answer Here: 
set /a test=%oneplusone%*1
if %test%==0 goto notValid
if %oneplusone%==2 goto correct
if %oneplusone% neq 2 goto incorrect

:correct
cls
echo Correct!
pause
goto youranswer

:incorrect
cls
echo Wrong.
pause
goto youranswer

:notValid
cls
echo Your input is not valid

pause
goto youranswer

:youranswer
cls
echo You answered: %oneplusone%
```